# how to add quantity respected product size in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute

How to add quantity respected product size in Magento 1.9

Please Help me

Comment: like i have product in multi pal size and every size has respected quantity so how to set   quantity

Comment: you can add quantity for particular product from admin Catalog->Product

Comment: i want to add quantity for particular size of product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Admin Panel **Catalog->Product**, edit the configurable product whose child product's size you want to change.

Now From Left side tab menu  Select **Associated Products**, here you will see list of the associated products, edit the product which you want to update, Then from inventory tab you can update the qunatity

Comment: Associated product create a new product for particular size but i want to on product in different size with different quantity

Comment: if you want one product in different size with different quantity then you have to create a configurable product and one associate product for each size

Comment: check this -  http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-configurable.html